# Uncaught TypeError: work.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: work.filter is not a function
    at computing_experience.js:7
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at computing_experience.js:5
```

when running the filter method on an array (imported from a separate file) anyone have any ideas?

```
import workExpArray from "../Arrays/workExpArray.js";

const workx = document.querySelector(".workexp");

const newArticle = workExpArray.map((work) => {
  let arrayItem = work
    .filter(function (workexp) {
      if (workexp.industry === "Computing") {
        return true;
      } else if (workexp.industry != "Computing") {
        return false;
      }
    })
    .map((workexp) => {
      let workExpArticle = document.createElement("article");
      workExpArticle.classList.add("workexp__article");
      workExpArticle.setAttribute("id", workexp.id);
      if (typeof workexp.secondaryRole === "string") {
        workExpArticle.innerHTML = `
              <SOME HTML HERE>
          `;
      } else {
        workExpArticle.innerHTML = `
              <MORE HTML HERE>
          `;
      }
      return workExpArticle;
    });
  if (workexp.industry === "Computing") {
    arrayItem.forEach((workexp) => {
      workx.append(workexp);
    });
  }
});
```

This is my first question on here and I'm reasonably new to writing code, so you may need more context :) let me know if so!

Thanks for any help!
Ollie

Comment: What is `workExpArray`?

Comment: Can you please share your workExpArray ? ( Just only a small piece which is required in above code)

Comment: an array, containing objects (one of the properties being "industry" with various values, in this case the value I am trying to keep is "Computing" and I am trying to filter out all objects with other values)

Comment: const workExpArray = [
  johnsonMatthey2WorkExp,
  digWorkExp,
  dunBriWorkExp,
  johnsonMattheyWorkExp,
  cons3WorkExp,
  barmans4WorkExp,
  carerWorkExp,
  barmans3WorkExp,
  cons2WorkExp,
  barmans2WorkExp,
  infaTechWorkExp,
  barmans1WorkExp,
  cons1WorkExp,
  imanamiWorkExp,
  tescoWorkExp,
];

(each variable in the array is an object, also imported from separate files)

Comment: const imanamiWorkExp = new workExpClass(
  // some properties here
  "Computing",
  // more properties here
);

Comment: Can you share how you export the workExpArray in your workExpArray.js file? This is probably the issue here.

Comment: @livingtheOKlife The problem is  work is not an array it's an object that was passed in array ( workExpArray) !  ... Try using `workExpArray.filter` instead of  `work.filter`

Comment: if the items inside the workExpArray array are objects that means they don't have the filter function in them, filter is the function that is only accessible  to arrays not objects

Comment: Chirag you are spot on my good man! Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error occurs when you call `work.filter` it seems to me that the `work` is not an array due to which there is no function named `filter` to call, that's why error is thrown. Make sure your imported array is 2 dimensional meaning it's elements are also arrays

Comment: aaaahhaa, I think you might be onto something! cheers bud, I'll give it a look!

Comment: You were spot on buddy! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are try to call `.filter` method on an object !  (work) instead of calling it on work I think what you wanted was to call it on workExpArray ....

Solution =>

```
 // Note used workExpArray intead of work ! 

const newArticle =  workExpArray.map((work) => {
let arrayItem = workExpArray.filter(function (workexp) {
    if (workexp.industry === "Computing") {
    return true;
    } else if (workexp.industry != "Computing") {
    return false;
    }
    });
    
    // ..... further code 
});
```

Comment: I'll try this change out shortly and let you know how it goes! Thanks bud!